# c - successive calloc calls corrupt some memory

Tags: c, memory-management, calloc

The code looks something like:

```
char *global1 = NULL;
char *global2 = NULL;
char *global3 = NULL;
char *global4 = NULL;

void func2(char *gPtr, char **gPtrToInitialize)
{
    if(*gPtrToInitialize == NULL)                     // Here, gPtr is correct
    {
        *gPtrToInitialize = dlcalloc(MAX_PATH, 1);      
    }                              // Here, gPtr has trailing junk characters

    // Do some initialization
}

void func1()
{
    if(global1 == NULL)
    {
        global1 = dlcalloc(MAX_PATH, 1);
    }
    func2(global1, &global2);
    func2(global1, &global3);
    func2(global1, &global4);

    // Do other tasks

    // Free all allocated global variables
}
```

**Note:**
In the above code, `dlcalloc` refers to code defined in Doug Lea's [malloc.c](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c).

---

**Before the `calloc` inside `func2()`,**

`gPtr` = "C:\Program Files\Test\Path.txt"

**After the `calloc` inside `func2()`,**

`gPtr` = "C:\Program Files\Test\Path.txt♂"

---

My question is, do successive `dlcalloc()` calls have a small chance of corrupting some other variable's memory? The above code is a generalization of a part of a large code base for something I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys I just solved my problem. This was what was happening in `func2()`:

- `gPtr` pointed to `0x009b0038`.
- `strlen("C:\Program Files\Test\Path.txt")` = 30 bytes.
- `*gPtrToInitialize` on allocation pointed to `0x009b0057` which starts *exactly* after `gPtr`'s section ends.
- Since the string pointed to by `gPtr` doesn't have a trailing '\0', any string operation on `gPtr` actually went into `*gPtrToInitialize`'s memory too.

All this was solved when I simply added a trailing `'\0'`.

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

dlcalloc shouldn't have any chance of corrupting any other part of memory unless there is a bug in it (which is unlikely).  It should either work or fail but shouldn't corrupt anything.

I think that you should look at your use of pointers because in your code above you are passing the address of global2, global3 and global4 to func2.  These addresses should never be null and so the call to dlcalloc in func2 should never happen.

I suspect that func2 should look like:

```
void func2(char *gPtr, char **gPtrToInitialize)
{
    if(*gPtrToInitialize == NULL)                     // Here, gPtr is correct
    {
        *gPtrToInitialize = dlcalloc(MAX_PATH, 1);      
    }                              // Here, gPtr has trailing junk characters

    // Do some initialization
}
```

I would look elsewhere in your code for similar pointer errors which are much more likely to cause memory corruption.

C pointers are dangerous.